# Deleting range and creating AutoFilters in multiple tabs

Tags: vba, excel

I wanted to write a macro which will create AutoFilter, if not present, drop filters and delete specific range in some tabs in my workbook.

I created this code but somehow it doesn't work - data gis deleted only from one tab instead of all that are not listed in If statement. Please help!

```
Sub ClearTabs()

Dim rng As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set rng = Range("B9:AK100")

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    If ws.Name <> "lastfile" And ws.Name <> "Sheet1" And ws.Name <> "Sheet2" Then

        If Not ws.AutoFilterMode Then
            ws.Range("B8:AK8").AutoFilter
        End If
    ws.AutoFilter.ShowAllData
    rng.ClearContents

    End If

Next ws

End Sub
```

Comment: How many sheets do you have besides these 3 sheets ? Also , you set your rng outside the ws loop, move it inside and fully qualify it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following my comment above, You need to set the Range (`Set rng = Range("B9:AK100")`) inside the `For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets` loop.

**Code**:

```
Sub ClearTabs()

Dim rng As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    With ws
        Select Case .Name
            Case "lastfile", "Sheet1", "Sheet2"
                ' do nothing
            Case Else
                Set rng = .Range("B9:AK100")

                If Not .AutoFilterMode Then
                    .Range("B8:AK8").AutoFilter
                End If
                .AutoFilter.ShowAllData
                rng.ClearContents
        End Select
    End With
Next ws

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! Your method works. Since it is slightly different to how I was trying to do that - can you tell me where was the mistake in my code?

Comment: yes, just move your `Set rng = Range("B9:AK100")` in the beginning of your code, to the line after `For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets` , and use `Set rng = ws.Range("B9:AK100")` , but don't you prefer to use this cleaner version ?

Comment: It does, thank you! I wanted to make sure where I made the mistake - agree that your version is cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

you can avoid dimming and setting `rng` and go like this

```
Option Explicit

Sub ClearTabs()
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        With ws
            If .Name <> "lastfile" And .Name <> "Sheet1" And .Name <> "Sheet2" Then
                If .AutoFilterMode Then
                    .AutoFilter.ShowAllData
                Else
                    .Range("B8:AK8").AutoFilter
                End If
                .Range("B9:AK100").ClearContents
            End If
        End With
    Next
End Sub
```